# How to get the value of a very specific XML element...?

Tags: php, xml

Suppose I have this in a file called data.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
     <stats>
        <data1>lorem</data1>
        <data2>ipsum</data2>
        <source mount="/mno">
            <thing>1.0</thing>
            <somethingelse>10</somethingelse>
            <important>12345</important>
            <more>word</more>
        </source>
        <source mount="/pqr">
            <thing>1.0</thing>
            <somethingelse>10</somethingelse>
            <important>23456</important>
            <more>word</more>
        </source>
        <source mount="/stu">
            <thing>1.0</thing>
            <somethingelse>10</somethingelse>
            <important>34567</important>
            <more>word</more>
        </source>
        <source mount="/vwx">
            <thing>1.0</thing>
            <somethingelse>10</somethingelse>
            <important>45678</important>
            <more>word</more>
        </source>
    </stats>
```

I now need to extract the contents of specifically the element `<important>` that's under `<source mount="/stu">`, and display this on a web page.
I figured out I can do that like this:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("data.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
echo $xml->source[3]->important;
?>
```

This actually works. What I do here is go to the third `<source>` which happens to be the one I need. However... The contents of the XML may (and will) change, and when that happens, `<source mount="/stu">` may not be the third one anymore, which means the output would no longer be that of the specific element I need here.

How do I make it so that it will always display the contents of `<important>` from specifically `<source mount="/stu">`, even if the number of items in the XML changes?

I've been told XPATH could be the way to go, but coding is not my profession, and I find it hard to get my head around... I've also studied some other XML related questions here on StackOverflow, but my novice brain does not understand how to apply those to my situation.
So any advise would be welcome here. Is XPATH indeed a good idea? If so, how do I implement/use that here. Or are there other/better ways of doing this?

Many thanks.

Comment: XPath is the way to proceed with this definitely. Load the XML into a DOMDocument instance, create the XPath and craft the query to look for `//source[@mount="/stu"]/important`

Comment: Running this through libxml there are quite a few errors with this xml mainly coming from the initial two `data` tags which are not closed correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is that you could loop over all `$xml->source` and exit from the loop when the value is `important` like so using a foreach loop:

```
<?php
    $xml=simplexml_load_file("data.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    foreach($xml->source as $source){
        if($source['mount'] == '/stu'){
            echo $source->important;
            break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: This works perfectly!

That is, if I change `if($source['mount'] === '/stu'){` to `if($source['mount'] == '/stu'){`

Brilliant! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah yes, thats right, `==` instead of `===` - good catch. Code updated. Please accept the answer if you are happy with it.

Comment: By accepting this answer, you've fallen into a common trap: coding the solution using a tool you're familiar with, rather than learning how to use a more powerful tool that's better suited to the job. It's easy to imagine that this reduces the amount of mental effort you have to make, but by the time you've debugged a few hundred lines of such code, you'll have invested just as much effort as if you had picked up an XPath tutorial and learned the more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: OP didn't ask for the most optimum/performant or best way to achieve the result. I clearly prefixed my answer with `One way...` I have used xpath in the past but my own preference is to do it the way I have suggested. More than one way to skin a cat etc...

Comment: I am experimenting with Xpath right now as well though, and got that working as well, thanks to the answer of Mads Hansen below.

Comment: @SimonK Suppose I would like to (also) echo a list of each `source` element, along with its own accompanying `important` element. Would that be possible with an adjustment to your code?

Answer (score 2):

Using DOMDocument & DOMXPath make the task of retrieving particular nodes from within a simple XML file like this quite straightforward.

The XML posted contained errors with the `data` tags as mentioned - these were caught by `libxml` as it has it's own error handling routines.

```php
$xml='<stats>
        <data1>lorem</data1>
        <data2>ipsum</data2>
        <source mount="/mno">
            <thing>1.0</thing>
            <somethingelse>10</somethingelse>
            <important>12345</important>
            <more>word</more>
        </source>
        <source mount="/pqr">
            <thing>1.0</thing>
            <somethingelse>10</somethingelse>
            <important>23456</important>
            <more>word</more>
        </source>
        <source mount="/stu">
            <thing>1.0</thing>
            <somethingelse>10</somethingelse>
            <important>34567</important>
            <more>word</more>
        </source>
        <source mount="/vwx">
            <thing>1.0</thing>
            <somethingelse>10</somethingelse>
            <important>45678</important>
            <more>word</more>
        </source>
    </stats>';


libxml_use_internal_errors( true ) ;
$dom=new DOMDocument();
$dom->validateOnParse=false;
$dom->recover=true;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
$dom->loadXML( $xml );
$errors=libxml_get_errors();

$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
if( $xp ){
    $expr='//source[@mount="/stu"]/important';
    $col=$xp->query( $expr );
    
    if( $col && $col->length > 0 )echo $col->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

The XPath expression `$expr='//source[@mount="/stu"]/important';` says to find any `source` node that has an attribute `mount` that exactly equals the desired string `/stu` - considerably more complex matching of nodes and attributes can be done than this.

This outputs:

```
34567
```

Answer (score 2):

With XPath, you describe what you want to select. Starting form the top of the document at the "root node" with `/` and then "walk" down the levels of the tree with each "step".

If you are looking for all of the `important` elements that are children of `source` elements, which are children of `stats`:

```
/stats/source/important
```

Or you could look for `important` elements anywhere, at any level within the document with:

```
//important
```

And if you only want the `important` element that is a child of `source` with the attribute `mount="/stu"`:

```
/stats/source[@mount="/stu"]/important
```

Applied:

```
$result = $xml->xpath('/stats/source[@mount="/stu"]/important'); 
foreach ($result as $important){
    echo '/stats/source[@mount="/stu"]/important: ', $important, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Yes. This indeed works as well. Thank you. I am experimenting with this right now.
One question though, if I may... How can I use this to echo a list of each `source` element, along with its own `important` element?
Thanks!

Comment: Addition... I mean, I can see how to get all `important` elements that are children of both `source` and `stats` through `/stats/source/important`, but I cannot get it to output a list of all sources, where it would echo `/mno`, `/pqr`, `/stu` and `/vwx`.
I can get it to display any other element now with XPath thanks to you, but just not the contents of the source element.
Thanks!